# Phonegap developer and built app differences

Tags: cordova, phonegap-developer-app

I am making a mobile app using phonegap. Now, for testing I use phonegap developer program, which allows me to `phonegap serve` the folder with html/js and instantly load that on ios and android devices. The question is, is it guaranteed that what I see after connection to the server in Phonegap Developer is identical to what I am going to get after building apk/ipa? In other words, can I skip testing built apps and release them being sure that everything works and looks **exactly** as in developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is yes, what you see using the PhoneGap Developer app is the same as how it would look if you were to install it with the build file. At least that is what is written at the end of the second paragraph of [this blog.](http://devgirl.org/2014/04/22/introducing-the-phonegap-developer-app/)

however...

If your app requires plugins or uses a backend database / local storage then it would not be an intelligent thing to do.

**Plugins**

When you `phonegap-serve` the app PhoneGap will include the core plugins but not third party ones, so it would be a good idea here to use a build process to install it onto a device so that plugins can be tested properly.

**Backend servers and local storage**

If your app needs to synchronise data between a backend server and the app's local storage you won't be able to test how the app handles this in offline mode because setting your device to being offline will lose the connection to the web server created using the `phonegap-serve` command. To do this you would require the app be installed and use Android's ADB or something similar.

**Config**

The `config.xml` file may also contain errors or may be missing settings that could cause problems with your app. The only way to truly find out is by building it and installing to the device. So for example you may miss whitelisting configuration for your API access or your plugins may be referenced wrong or missing.

There could be more issues involved but these are the things the first come to mind without doing too much research into it.

Comment: Yes, but for testing offline mode I could just make my backend inaccessible, couldn't I?

Comment: You could do or you could set an `offline` flag where you make your API calls to skip the call. But one issue here would be you don't get to see your error callback code run which might contain errors.

Comment: Also this won't emulate things like 2G connection if you plan on testing that too. I suppose it does depend per application and what you need to test

Comment: Thank you, I don't have anything except html/js in my app, so things like 2G and plugins don't matter. The question was about ajaxing built-in html pages, localStorage and other javascript stuff, which is kinda shady when used without domain name. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: One other thing that came to mind would be the configuration of your `config.xml` file. The only true way to know it is OK would be to do a test build first. I guess this would be more related to when you use plugins etc though. Just something for you to think about though